# How to plot species richness against altitude for these columns in R?

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I'm just trying to familiarise myself with this language for the future and was looking for some help with manipulating and plotting data. So I have imported data from excel with a set number of columns, and I'm looking to plot the species richness of birds against altitude. The data within the two columns looks something like this:

```
Species Altitude (m) 
Species A 100 
Species B 100 
Species C 100 
Species D 100 
Species E 100 
Species C 200 
Species D 200 
Species E 200 
Species A 300 
Species C 300 
Species D 300 
Species E 300 
Species B 400 
Species E 400 
Species B 500 
Species D 500
```

My question is how would I manipulate the data to sum the number of species found at each altitude and present it as a plot without using ggplot2? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not want to use `ggplot`? It has all the tools, together with the `tidyverse` to creat your plot quickly.

Comment: have a look at table() to get your counts

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` to `sum` `Altitude` for each `Species` and then use `barplot` to plot it.

```
tmp <- aggregate(Altitude~Species, df, sum)
barplot(tmp$Altitude, names.arg = tmp$Species,xlab = 'Species', ylab = 'Altitude')
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Species = c("SpeciesA", "SpeciesB", "SpeciesC", 
"SpeciesD", "SpeciesE", "SpeciesC", "SpeciesD", "SpeciesE", "SpeciesA", 
"SpeciesC", "SpeciesD", "SpeciesE", "SpeciesB", "SpeciesE", "SpeciesB", 
"SpeciesD"), Altitude = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 400L, 400L, 500L, 500L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
## loding the data
species <- read.csv(text='Species,Altitude
Species A,100
Species B,100
Species C,100
Species D,100
Species E,100
Species C,200
Species D,200
Species E,200
Species A,300
Species C,300
Species D,300
Species E,300
Species B,400
Species E,400
Species B,500
Species D,500', header=T)
species
#>      Species Altitude
#> 1  Species A      100
#> 2  Species B      100
#> 3  Species C      100
#> 4  Species D      100
#> 5  Species E      100
#> 6  Species C      200
#> 7  Species D      200
#> 8  Species E      200
#> 9  Species A      300
#> 10 Species C      300
#> 11 Species D      300
#> 12 Species E      300
#> 13 Species B      400
#> 14 Species E      400
#> 15 Species B      500
#> 16 Species D      500
## transforming species to data.table
data.table::setDT(species)

species = species[, .(`Number of Species` = .N), by = c("Altitude")]

barplot(species$`Number of Species`, names.arg=species$Altitude, xlab='Altitude', ylab='Number of Species')
```

[image]

the `.N` gives the count of the rows for the current group, the `by` specifies by which column to group. this returns a `data.table` with `Altitude` and `Number of Species` columns.
for an introduction on the `data.table` arguably one of the fastest packages for `data.frame` manipulation check the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `aggregate()` to aggregate your dataset by species or by altitude, using any existing function or defining a new one.

In your case, I would just use the function `length()` to aggregate as it returns the number of cases in each group. If you have multiple counts of the same species in one altitude, it might be wise to define a function that returns the number of different species.

You could also use a function to compute the entropy of species (if you want to get the diversity) or the gini coefficient (if you want a measure for dominance).

```
luniq = function(v){
  return(length(unique(v)))
}

d = data.frame("Species"=c("Species A","Species B","Species C","Species D",
                           "Species E","Species C","Species D","Species E",
                           "Species A","Species C","Species D","Species E",
                           "Species B","Species E","Species B","Species B"),
               "Altitude (m)"=c(100,100,100,100,
                                100,200,200,200,
                                300,300,300,300,
                                400,400,500,500))

agg1 = aggregate(d[["Species"]]~d[["Altitude..m."]],FUN=length)
agg2 = aggregate(d[["Species"]]~d[["Altitude..m."]],FUN=luniq)


d = data.frame("Number.Species"=agg1[,2],
               "Number.Different"=agg2[,2],
               row.names=agg[,1])

barplot(t(as.matrix(d)),beside=T,legend.text=names(d))
```

Note that I changed the altitude 500 to contain two exemplars of the same species. So, the count still is 2, but the number of different species is 1.

[image]